# Creating two columns, one containing random number and another one first column cubed

Tags: python, python-3.x

As the title says, I just want to create two columns, one has 100 random numbers and another one has cubed value from the first column. This is my attempt:

```
import pandas as p
import numpy as n

c1 = list()
c2 = list()
for n in range (0, 99):
    c1 = [randint()]
    c2 = c1*c1*c1
    
print (c1, c2)
```

I thought the randint() function is built-in, but it gives an error message.

Comment: hi, perhaps `import random` , then use it `print random.randint(0, 5)`

Comment: You need to import the random module or use the numpy randint function since you already have numpy imported

Answer (score 0):

I believe that you missed:

```py
from random import randint
```

Answer (score 0):

There are several problems with the current code:

- you are importing the libraries in a very uncommon way. It is much more common to import `numpy as np` or `pandas as pd`.
- `randint()` needs to called properly. It is not built-in function in python. It is a method under `np.random` so, either do `from numpy.random import randint` at the importing stage or use it like below. Also, `randint()` excepts some arguments.
- `range(0,99)` will only generate 99 numbers for you. You should use `range(0,100)` or `range(100)`.
- You can't do `c1*c1*c1` with `lists`.  You need to do this for each element. You can use list comprehension (see below). Alternatively, you can convert `lists` in `numpy array` with `c1 = np.array(c1)` and then do `c1*c1*c1`.

Here is a working solution:

```
import numpy as np

#using list comprehension to generate 100 random numbers between 0 to 9
c1 = [np.random.randint(10) for i in range(100)]

#using list comprehension to cube each number 
c2 = [x*x*x for x in c1]

print(c1)
print(c2)
```

Output:

```
[6 9 3 4 4 0 4 5 5 4 8 7 6 2 7 8 5 6 9 0 4 6 6 1 4 1 2 4 3 2 6 0 1 5 5 6 9
 5 2 3 1 4 9 1 8 5 8 1 3 1 0 9 2 5 0 7 9 1 8 9 7 7 2 5 0 2 9 1 0 2 4 4 9 3
 3 9 8 0 5 5 2 9 8 2 4 2 7 3 2 6 8 1 5 9 4 6 3 4 2 8]

[216 729  27  64  64   0  64 125 125  64 512 343 216   8 343 512 125 216
 729   0  64 216 216   1  64   1   8  64  27   8 216   0   1 125 125 216
 729 125   8  27   1  64 729   1 512 125 512   1  27   1   0 729   8 125
   0 343 729   1 512 729 343 343   8 125   0   8 729   1   0   8  64  64
 729  27  27 729 512   0 125 125   8 729 512   8  64   8 343  27   8 216
 512   1 125 729  64 216  27  64   8 512]
```

Answer (score 0):

Since you are already familiar with `numpy`, you could use the numpy random function and generate `n` amount of random integers with the largest possible integer being the `range_limit` as follows:

```py
from numpy import random
c1 = random.randint(range_limit, size=(n))
c2 = [i**3 for i in c1]
```

So to generate 5 values between 0 and 100;

```
c1 = random.randint(100, size=(5))
```

And then cube them